# How do you make a spinner pick from different lists?

Tags: android, arrays, string, list, spinner

As of rite now all I have is one spinner with three options, what i would like to do is if option one is selected then a random from list1 is selected, option 2 picks from list 2 and so on, I have a small portion of code written just enough to declare the spinner and populate it with choices, where do i go from here? Thanks is advance!

Here is my code on my xml:

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/alcohol"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:prompt="@string/prompt" />
```

Then this is on my .java file:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
 // Set Alcohol Spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.alcohol);
 // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
         R.array.alcohol, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 // Apply the adapter to the spinner
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to get the item when you select from spinner.If it is so then try this.

```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new listener_Of_spinner());
```

// Listener Implementation of Spinner For Selecting Room

```
public static class listener_Of_spinner implements OnItemSelectedListener 
{    static String getSelectedItem;
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) 
   {   
      // By using this you can get the position of item which you have selected from the dropdown 
      getSelectedItem = (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)).toString();
   }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {           
      // Do nothing.
    }
};
```

Hope this may be useful